# Why won't my image align to the right? CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment, margin

I am stuck on this simple issue. How the heck do I align my image to the right border of the box? I tried float:right, align-self: end, margin: -4em, I tried most things I found online but nothing.
As you can see I put the image through CSS as a background image for a div. I am stuck.

how it should look
[image: how it should look like]

how it is
[image: how it is]

```css
  body{
    background-color: hsl(233, 47%, 7%);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 6em;
  }
  .all{
    background-color: hsl(244, 38%, 16%);
    width: 80em;
    height: 28em;
    border-radius: 0.725em;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
  }
  .bella{
    background-image: url(images/image-header-desktop.jpg);
    height: 30em;
    width: 30em;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    contain: content;
    display: inline-block;    
    background-position: right;
    align-self: flex-end;
    clear: left;
    float: right;
  }
  .writings{
    font-family: 'Inter';
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    max-width: 30em ;
    margin: 6em;
  }
  .writings h1{
    font-weight: 700;
    color: white;
  }
  #viola{
    color: hsl(277, 64%, 61%);
  }
  .writings p{
    color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.75);
    font-weight: 400;
  }
  .figures{
    display: flex;
  }
  .figures h2{
    font-weight: 700;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Inter';
  }
  .figures h5{
    color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.6);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Lexend Deca';
    letter-spacing: 2px;
  }
  .fig1{
    padding-right: 5em;
  }
HTML
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="tutto"></div>
    <div class="all">
      <div class="writings">
          <h1>Get <span id="viola">insights</span> that help your business grow.</h1>
          <p> Discover the benefits of data analytics and make better decisions regarding revenue, customer 
            experience, and overall efficiency.</p>
          <div class="figures">
            <div class="fig1"><h2>10k+</h2><h5> companies</h5></div>
            <div class="fig1"><h2>1314</h2><h5> templates</h5></div>
            <div class="fig1"><h2>12M+</h2><h5> queries</h5></div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="bella"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you specially need the image to be in its own element? To me it looks like part of the background.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `float` you had set on the div with the background image. This is not needed with `flex`. Then set your height and width to `100%`. I added a dummy image for demonstration purposes. See below.

```css
body {
  background-color: hsl(233, 47%, 7%);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 6em;
}

.all {
  background-color: hsl(244, 38%, 16%);
  width: 80em;
  height: 28em;
  border-radius: 0.725em;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
}

.bella {
  background-image: url(https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  /* background-repeat: no-repeat; */
  contain: content;
  display: inline-block;
  background-position: right;
  /* align-self: flex-end; */
  /* clear: left; */
  /* float: right; */
}

.writings {
  font-family: 'Inter';
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 30em;
  margin: 6em;
}

.writings h1 {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: white;
}

#viola {
  color: hsl(277, 64%, 61%);
}

.writings p {
  color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.75);
  font-weight: 400;
}

.figures {
  display: flex;
}

.figures h2 {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Inter';
}

.figures h5 {
  color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.6);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Lexend Deca';
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.fig1 {
  padding-right: 5em;
}

HTML
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="tutto"></div>
  <div class="all">
    <div class="writings">
      <h1>Get <span id="viola">insights</span> that help your business grow.</h1>
      <p> Discover the benefits of data analytics and make better decisions regarding revenue, customer experience, and overall efficiency.</p>
      <div class="figures">
        <div class="fig1">
          <h2>10k+</h2>
          <h5> companies</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="fig1">
          <h2>1314</h2>
          <h5> templates</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="fig1">
          <h2>12M+</h2>
          <h5> queries</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bella"></div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I would try to set the height to 100%. Then consider to make both sides equally wide, if you want it to look exactly like the "how it should look" version. Additionally, your picture has to have the right nativ width and height so that it is as big as the left side of your div.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in the image you have to attach an image with fixed sizes and if you do not have a fixed size use: `background-position: center center; background-size: cover;` in this way the image will be spread all over the space without being repeated. If you have a still image, you only need `width: 100%;` and `height: 100%;` , the rest will work automatically.

```css
body {
  background-color: hsl(233, 47%, 7%);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 6em;
}
.all {
  background-color: hsl(244, 38%, 16%);
  width: 80em;
  height: 28em;
  border-radius: 0.725em;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
}
.bella {
  background-image: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/08/25/20/42/field-6574455__340.jpg);
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
}
.writings {
  font-family: "Inter";
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 30em;
  margin: 6em;
}
.writings h1 {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: white;
}
#viola {
  color: hsl(277, 64%, 61%);
}
.writings p {
  color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.75);
  font-weight: 400;
}
.figures {
  display: flex;
}
.figures h2 {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Inter";
}
.figures h5 {
  color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.6);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Lexend Deca";
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
.fig1 {
  padding-right: 5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="tutto"></div>
<div class="all">
  <div class="writings">
    <h1>Get <span id="viola">insights</span> that help your business grow.</h1>
    <p> Discover the benefits of data analytics and make better decisions regarding revenue, customer
      experience, and overall efficiency.</p>
    <div class="figures">
      <div class="fig1">
        <h2>10k+</h2>
        <h5> companies</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="fig1">
        <h2>1314</h2>
        <h5> templates</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="fig1">
        <h2>12M+</h2>
        <h5> queries</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bella"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please consider explaining your solution. Code dumps are **never** helpful.

Comment: Please provide some explanation for your solution. See [ask].

Comment: I always follow the solution, Have a little patience, please, I'm not employed. I just wanted to be the first to post after I clarified. if my solution works well it would not be logical to have minus ... pff

Comment: @Sergiu sometimes a well-explained answer with supporting code is better than being first.

Comment: okey, sorry ) I will do so